# used instant variable inside the object define function

Tags: javascript

i need to used instant variable inside the object define function like that .

i need to use `Result` variable outside the function

```
function Request(params,type,url){

        var loginReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
        loginReq.open(type,url);
        loginReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        loginReq.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
        loginReq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "image/png;charset=utf-8");
        loginReq.send(params);
        loginReq.onload = function()
        {
            var json = this.responseText;
            var Result = JSON.parse(json);
        };
        return Result;
  };

exports.Request = Request;
```

i need to return Result Or use it outside the scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use either a callback, or a [promise library](https://github.com/kriskowal/q)

**Using a callback**

```
function Request(params,type,url,callback){
    //...
    loginReq.onload = function() {
        var json = this.responseText;
        var Result = JSON.parse(json);
        callback(Result);
    };
};

//Somewhere else 
Request(/**/,/**/,/**/,function(result){
    //use result
});
```

**Using a promise library like Q**

```
var Q = require("q");
function Request(params,type,url,callback){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    //...
    loginReq.onload = function() {
        var json = this.responseText;
        var Result = JSON.parse(json);
        deferred.resolve(Result);
    };
    return deferred.promise;
};

//Somewhere else
Request(/**/,/**/,/**/).then(function(result){
   //use result
});
```

Comment: thanx for your answer, but i didnt exactly understand the callback function. kindly explain that ,,

Comment: its just a function you pass and then call when your processing is done